# Prove or disprove inequality using other inequality

Tags: inequality

> if $3x^2+2ax+b+5\sin 2x >0$, then prove/disprove that $a^2-3b+15<0$.($x\in \mathbb R$)

If disproven find correct inequality relating $a,b$

I don't know where to start. Any hint will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In the best case
$$3x^2+2ax+b+5>0$$
Thus, the quadratic form does not change in sign and has no root
$$\Delta<0$$

$$(2a)^2-4(3)(b+5)<0$$

divided by 4

$$a^2-(3)(b+5)<0$$